# Textbox numeric values is already inserted in other textbox avoid duplicates

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

[image]I have a 12 texbox I have a validation on it, that you can only input the numbers 1 to 10, what I want is if I input 1 in first textbox you cannot input it that number in the second textbox and in other textbox,  and when you input 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 10 in other textbox then you cannot use that number anymore because it is already inserted in the remaining textbox otherwise the number will transfer to other remaining textbox, so that the 1-10 numeric values will get occupied in the 10 texboxes out of 12 texboxes without duplicates and you cannot input on other 2 textboxes because the numbers 1-10 is occupied, can someone help me please.....Im using a Asp.net. vb.net code for the requirements..

```
    <div class="container">
      <p>d. Suppose that there is 12 fields of question Please rank only them from 1 - 10 .</p>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8" >
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td>

              <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" CssClass="Validators" Display="Dynamic"
    MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="10" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="Textbox37"
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Input digits 1 to 10" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RangeValidator>
          </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />      
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="I love the place" />

     </td>   
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="the business location is great"/>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox3" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="Im gettin out of time"/>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox4" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="My life is consumed." />
     </td>   
     </tr>

      <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox5" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="the work place is unstable" />
     </td>   
     </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox6" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="Opportunity to work is great" />
     </td>   
     </tr>

        <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox7" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="I love the salary" />

     </td>   
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox8" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="My superior is not ok"/>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox9" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="I had so many vacant time"/>
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox10" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="I don't like to waste time in idle hours" />
     </td>   
     </tr>

         <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox11" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="These is the place you want to be" />
     </td>   
     </tr>

      <tr>
     <td>
     <asp:Textbox ID="Textbox12" runat="server" style="text-align:center" onkeypress="return IsNumeric8(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" />
     <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" Text="I'm having a hard time on these!" />
     </td>   
     </tr>

     </table>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>   
       </div>
```

..... can someone help me I'm doing these for a week I cannot find a answer my life is consumed without doing other things just to get read of this please help me....

Comment: jQuery can come up with easy solution for this, can you use jQuery or restricted with VB.Net server side solution?

Comment: Can you help me with that....

Comment: Yes writing a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution, I tested it.

Step 1: add a css class to all textboxes (can be a dummy css class just to tag textboxes), like

```
<asp:Textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" style="text-align:center"   Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" CssClass="txtclass" />      
<asp:Textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" style="text-align:center"   Height="20px" MaxLength="2" Width="22px" CssClass="txtclass" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(".txtclass").blur(function () {
     isDuplicateValue(); // You can call this function on a button click
     textboxesToggle();
})


function textboxesToggle() {
                var boxesWithValue = $('.txtclass').filter(function () { return this.value != '' });
                if (boxesWithValue.length == 10) {
                    var emptyboxes = $('.txtclass').filter(function () { return this.value == '' });
                    $(emptyboxes).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else {
                    $(".txtclass").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }


function isDuplicateValue() {
                var arr = [];
                var i = 0;
                //store values in array
                $(".txtclass").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() != '') {
                        arr[i++] = $(this).val();
                    }
                })

                console.log(arr);
                var sortedArray = arr.sort();
                //check for duplicates
                var duplicates = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (sortedArray[i + 1] == sortedArray[i]) {
                        duplicates.push(sortedArray[i]);
                    }
                }

                if (duplicates.length > 0) {
                    var dup = 'duplicates found: ';
                    for (var i = 0; i < duplicates.length; i++)
                        dup += duplicates[i] + ' , ';
                    alert(dup);
                }                    
            }
```

Comment: I paste the javascript inside the .aspx page <script type =text/javascript>Your Code Sami</script> but nothing happens...

Comment: It's working, created jsFiddle for you

https://jsfiddle.net/jscriptcoder/egg6usey/

Comment: Ive! created new .aspx page and add the script but its not working

Comment: Did you include jQuery file ?

Comment: I just paste it in inside <script type =text/javascript>yourcode</script> inside the .aspx page

Comment: Put this code in <head> tag <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sir if you have a visual studio asp.net you can try it.

Comment: First I tested in VS and then moved to JSFiddle

Comment: Thank you for your code I revised it and it works, its just the calling of java script your code is working. thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, so don't forget to accept and vote up my answer.

Comment: Thank you Pantera but you just accepted my answer, click on up arrow as well . Thank you :)